# "Add" Button for Data Frame Editing GUI in R

Tags: r, user-interface, for-loop, widget

I'm trying to create a GUI in R where the user can add, edit, or search entries within a data frame.  For adding a new entry I created the "Add" button which opens a new window.  The code is as follows:

```
Add     <- gbutton("Add Entry", 
               handler = function(h,...){
                Input <- gwindow("Input New Entry")
                Vals  <- ggroup(horizontal = F, use.scrollwindow = T, container = Input)
                COLS  <- 1:length(colnames(Data))
                Text  <- vector()
                for (n in COLS) {
                  ADDS    <- gedit(initial.msg = colnames(Data)[n], container = Vals)
                  Text[n] <- ADDS[]
                }
                SAVE  <- gbutton("Add Entry",horizontal = F, 
                          handler = function(h,...){
                            Tab[DIM[1]+1,] <- Text
                            DIM[1] = DIM[1] + 1
                            dispose(Input)
                          },       
                          container = Vals)
                },
                container = Bttns)
```

For reference `Data` is the original data frame used, `DIM` is the vector with the dimensions of the data frame, `Bttns` is the group in which the `Add` button appears in the original window, and `Tab` is the data frame table added in the original window with `gdf`.

My goal is to create a `gedit` for each column entry in `Data` and to then append the new entry as the last row in the original data frame.  Creating each `gedit`  manually seems to defeat the purpose of computer programming.  Is there a way I can save a vector of widgets?  The preceding code doesn't give any errors, but it doesn't save the data after it is entered into the new window.  Is there an easier way to do this other than using a for loop?  Any help is appreciated!